# Correct approach to apply HTML style in x-axis title

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to apply HTML style in x-axis title in my Highchart plot. However it looks like Highchart fails to apply style if it is within `<span>` tag.

Kindly refer to this link in the original Highchart plot :

http://jsfiddle.net/jam4z32c/4/

However, if I change the line #7 with the following statement, Highchart fails to apply the HTML style

```
text: "<p>Custom with <span style='color:blue'><b>simple</b></span> <i>markup</i></p>",
```

Any idea what is the right approach to apply HTML style contained within `<span>`.

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [xAxis.labels.useHTML](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.useHTML), It allows us to use html property in the labels

```
 title: {
  useHTML: true, //added this
  enabled: true,
  text: "<p>Custom with <span style='color:blue'><b>simple</b></span> <i>markup</i></p>",
  style: {
    fontWeight: 'normal'
  }
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4boxvj1w/) demo

Comment: Thnaks. How can I apply similar kind of styling in the Series label as in http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/events-addseries/ ? 'useHTML: true' doesnt look getting applied there.